# Parse local store for an App

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

Hi I am doing an android app that has a 3 different parse classes. Is there a way to store all the info from this classes in the local data store and sync them every time the app opens? (I just need to read the info from the server the app doesn't change any of the info of the db.) Also do I have to initialize the local data store in all the activities or only in the one that I get the info from the server? code samples would be appreciated. (I already read the documentation in parse.com but I am still confused in how the local data store works.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have all the data related to each class as local store inside your application ,and you can sync data with server.

To do this, you need to create a Application class in your project add `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());` among other properties recommended by Parse.com such as `Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");`
So this is a one time thing and local data store will work.

But to saving data specific for each class, you need to query data from Parse database and pin it to the local database.

Basically it happens like this

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override          
    public void onClick(View v) {

        todo.setTitle(todoText.getText().toString());
        todo.setDraft(true);    
        todo.setAuthor(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        todo.pinInBackground(TodoListApplication.TODO_GROUP_NAME,
                new SaveCallback() {            
                    @Override                          
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (isFinishing()) {                        
                        return;                                         
                    }                                           
                    if (e == null) {                            
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);                  
                        finish();                                       
                    } else {                                    
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),         
                                "Error saving: " + e.getMessage(),                      
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                              
                    }                                           
                }                                       
            });                                 
        }               
});
```

to sync only the latest data, you need to have a flag to recognize whether that data is already synced or not in your class.(as in the `todo.setDraft(true);` in this sample).

`TodoListApplication.TODO_GROUP_NAM`is the unique constant to identify the class specific for each local table. since this is saved in local data store, now you can query even without network connection to retrieve data.

```
  ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Todo> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Todo>() {
        public ParseQuery<Todo> create() {
            ParseQuery<Todo> query = Todo.getQuery();
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            query.fromLocalDatastore();
            return query;
        }
    };
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response, correct me if i am wrong but isn't your code to save what the user did in the device to the cloud? I want the opposite I am basically using parse so I don't have to update the database for each platform (iOS, Android and Web) when I ad something to the database but I am the onlyone that can change stuff, the users are read only.

Comment: Actually no, please checkout the given link for reference,
[link](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#pinInBackground(com.parse.SaveCallback))
This specifically says  **Stores the object and every object it points to in the local datastore, recursively**. 

To clarify :for saving , in Parse you should use `public void saveInBackground(SaveCallback callback)` method